# how can i end the pyautogui operation by pressing the escape key

Tags: python, pyautogui

This is the code now how can I End the process at anytime by pressing escape

or is there any way if I press cntrl + x it breaks the proccess

I tried many ways but its not working

```py
import pyautogui
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import keyboard

sg.theme('DarkBlue4')

LINKS = {
    'English': 'kpg-zobo-auc',
    'Biology': 'vrc-hgun-jtd',
    'Chemistry': 'sbm-mcdg-oht',
    'Physics': 'fir-vmhm-tkw',
    'Maths': 'ofm-zarb-hgx',
    'Hindi': 'rph-zsnk-wjg',
    'History': 'yaw-bwqb-ato',
    'Political Science': 'yaw-bwqb-ato',
    'Geography': 'djs-dbmi-gdf',
    'Economics': 'ydc-xxbk-qjy'
}

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please choose ONE class', auto_size_text=True)],
    [
        sg.Button('English'),
        sg.Button('Biology'),
        sg.Button('Chemistry'),
        sg.Button('Physics'),
        sg.Button('Maths'),
        sg.Button('Hindi'),
        sg.Button('History'),
        sg.Button('Political Science'),
        sg.Button('Geography'),
        sg.Button('Economics'),
        sg.Quit()
    ]
]

event, value = sg.Window('What class do you want to join ?', layout, icon='D:\IMPORTANT\Google_Meet_ICO.ico').read(
    close=True)


link = LINKS[event]

time.sleep(0.6)
pyautogui.press('win', interval=0.5)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.typewrite('chrome', interval=0.1)
time.sleep(0.3)
pyautogui.press('enter', interval=0.5)
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.typewrite('https://meet.google.com', interval=0.01)
pyautogui.press('enter', interval=0.5)
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(450, 660)
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.typewrite(link, interval=0.1)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('enter', interval=0.2)
time.sleep(4)
pyautogui.click(700, 710)
time.sleep(0.6)
pyautogui.click(760, 710)
time.sleep(0.8)
pyautogui.click(1270, 555)
print('Joined')
```

and also I keep running into this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "******************************************", line 43, in 
link = LINKS[event]
KeyError: 'Quit'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: There're two events no included in your dictionary `LINKS', 'Quit' for button, None for window close button. In those two cases, you will get exception `KeyError`.